# Position several divs in one parent div

Tags: css, html, position, parent

I already have seen a couple of questions going in this direction, but nothing helped. Everyone says just set the parent div position to relative and the child ones to absolute. But my problem is that every div is at the 0/0 point of my parent div. It seems the inner elements doesn't know from each other.

Here is what my page should look like:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/unbenanntgoc.png/

In my html I just define my divs:

```
<div id="content">

<div id="header" />
<div id="naviContent" />
<div id="imageContent" />
<div id="tagContent" />
<div id="textContent" />

</div>
```

So navi image and tag content divs should float.

And this is how my css looks like:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    background-color:#33FF00;
}

#header {
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
}

#naviContent {
    width:25%;
    background-color:#F0F;
    float:left;
}

#imageContent {
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
}

#tagContent {
    background-color:#900;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
}

#textContent {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    clear:both;
}

#content {
    height:1600px;  
    width:1200px;
    background-color:#999999;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
}
```

So maybe anyone can tell me why all my elements (black, yellow, red, grey and green) are positioned to the 0/0 point of the pink one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I'm guessing you've only been doing css/html for a little while? Remove the position relative from the header and remove the position absolute from the other items. The rest of your layout will come together easier for you when you do that.

Comment: Yeah, normally I'm just doing Java/Android programming. Okay thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the DIV properly -

```
<div id="content">

<div id="header">Header </div>
<div id="naviContent">Nav</div>
<div id="imageContent">Image</div>
<div id="tagContent"> Tags</div>
<div id="textContent">Text  </div>

</div>
```

**EDIT:** [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4hGz/1/) You need to adjust floated width and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute is not the standard way of laying out a page.

What you should do is just remove the position attribute, float everything left and set widths (please note you will need content in the div for it to render correctly).

You might want to look into CSS grid systems such as [960.gs](http://960.gs) as they handle this part of development for you in a standardised way using pre-defined classes.

Answer (score 0):

you should code like this : - http://tinkerbin.com/J9CCZXRL

**CSS**

```
#content {
background:pink;
  width:500px;
  padding:10px;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
}



#header {
  background:red;
  height:100px;

}

#left {
background:green;
  width:100px;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
}

#middle {
background:blue;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  height:400px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
#right {
background:yellow;
  width:100px;
  float:right;
  height:400px;
}

#footer {
background:grey;
height:100px;
  clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="middle"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```